# Check if keyboard and mouse are available with Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface

Is it possible to check if a keyboard and a mouse are connected to the system with Qt or any other C++ alternative? in windows

Comment: Good question. I think it is not possible with Qt, hence you have to use your own platform dependent calls. Some information about this [for windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798242/keyboard-mouse-input-in-c) and [for Linux/X11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182/linux-x11-input-library-without-creating-a-window) (well, not even sure you can get the availability information easily with platform specific code...)

Comment: Still with those answers you need to click or press a key...

Comment: Take a look at WMI programming here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx and then this class may be used to get the available keyboards: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx There's probably something similar for mouse too. Do you need to do this on other platforms as well?

Comment: no this should be running just on windows...BTW thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think Qt in embedded Linux can detect the plug and unplug of an USB Mouse and enable it when USB mouse is plugged in.

you can refer following links
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkbddriverplugin.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmousedriverplugin.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwsmousehandler.html